# Prettier with CSS settings in VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have the Prettier extension added to my VS Code editor.

When using Less or Sass, the default settings format code like this:

```css
// Default

.parent_selector {
  .child_selector {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```css
// Desired Format

.parent_selector {

  .child_selector {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

How could I tweak the Prettier CSS settings to achieve this? I know it seems trivial, but in bigger code bases it helps readability.

Comment: so you said Prettier doesn't work with less and sass, right?

Comment: The rule you want is that a blank line should be added after the start of a new nesting block? Or a blank line should be added before every rule within a scope?

Comment: @demo Prettier does work with Less and Sass: [Less example](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEABAtgTwLQCcCuANnAM5wxIAEwAOlJQ5QHRbZnFgwS7V2OMY4AEwCWAQ0owAbr3r9GAIzFgA1gHNcEfFCHZIhblQWFlKgNx95AX0sMbcqxaiDREgBTcRCGGJgjoSAAO3DC4YiIwAJSy-Bg4BMRkMG6RTlYgADQgEIF+0CTIoGK4mgDuAArFCAUoYlIQIkKZIAphquQAyoHKIlBqyKH4cFkAFjDohADqIxGk3WBwHdURIlIRmMjgJAVZvWS4MOVhauhiyABmYoRkWQBWJAAeAEJtKp1i6HAAMr1wF1c3ED3B4dXpqYgARXwEHg-2uwxA3Vw+02iR2iNwvRgk0aMBGyAAHAAGLKBTRkSZhQKbMmkOC4KR-LK4OAAR3wIhZRzEJzOSEu8KyZHQIgGBARJDBkOhsP5AIRPgUOKEeOQACYsqFwoQwQBhCDoU6bKDQJkgfBkAAqYgUNQFZCsViAA)

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Ideally I just want a space before every rule in a scope

Comment: Prettier is opinionated, so the Prettier tool tries not to provide too many options. I tried changing all of the options in the Prettier playground, but none of them achieved that effect. Therefore, you will have to accomplish this formatting change with some other CSS formatting tool. The solution might also use one of those tools that helps you set up a single command to run Prettier followed by another program that touches up Prettier’s formatting.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Yeah, that's pretty much the conclusion I just came to as well. Thanks  for looking!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method; It can be achieved by using [stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) plugin and [stylelint-config-standard](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard) rules.

```
npm install --save-dev stylelint stylelint-config-standard
```

After installing them, proceed with `ctrl+shift+p` on VS Code and run command: `stylelint: fix all auto-fixable problems`.

[image: stylelint: fix all auto-fixable problems]

PS: Consider assigning a keyboard shortcut for `stylelint: fix all auto-fixable problems` command for easy access.